# Search an SQL table that already contains wildcards?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains patters for phone numbers, where x can match any digit.

```
+----+--------------+----------------------+
| ID | phone_number | phone_number_type_id |
+----+--------------+----------------------+
|  1 | 1234x000x    |                    1 |
|  2 | 87654311100x |                    4 |
|  3 | x111x222x    |                    6 |
+----+--------------+----------------------+
```

Now, I might have 511132228 which will match with row 3 and it should return its type. So, it's kind of like SQL wilcards, but the other way around and I'm confused on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
select * from my_table
where '511132228' like replace(phone_number, 'x', '_')
```

Comment: How on earth did I never know about SqlFiddle.com?? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
select * 
from yourtable
where '511132228' like (replace(phone_number, 'x','_'))
```

Comment: Thanks, I selected the other answer, cause he has lower reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT ID,phone_number,phone_number_type_id
FROM TableName
WHERE '511132228' LIKE REPLACE(phone_number,'x','_');
```

Query with test data:

```
With TableName as
(

SELECT 3 ID, 'x111x222x' phone_number, 6 phone_number_type_id from dual
)

SELECT 'true' value_available
FROM TableName
WHERE '511132228' LIKE REPLACE(phone_number,'x','_');
```

The above query will return data if pattern match is available and will not return any row if no match is available.